# Problem with Incremental updates in Kafka Connect and Debezium (PostgreSql and MongoDB)

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

We have an environment set up with Kafka and Zookeeper. Our need is to send data from a PostgreSQL database to a MongoDB database through Kafka Connect.
We were able to perform the configuration and when initializing the connector, the data is initially migrated correctly.

However, we need that, when adding a new column or table in the connector configuration, the affected records are sent again for processing in our consumer so that they are manipulated and updated again in the MongoDB database.
Is there a way to do this, without having to migrate all the records again? We need to do this migration in stages because it's a lot of data.

Here is an example of our configuration:

```
{
"name": "migration_connector",
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "host.docker.internal",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "database.user": "postgres_user",
    "database.password": "postgres_pasword",
    "database.dbname" : "database_source",
    "database.server.name": "server_name",
    "schema.include": "public",
    "column.include.list": "public.customer.id_customer,public.customer.name,public.table_B.id,public.table_c.id ... and so on",
    "table.include.list": "public.customer,public.table_B,public.table_C",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "false",
    "heartbeat.interval.ms": 5000,
    "heartbeat.action.query": "INSERT INTO public.heartbeat_kafka_connect (id, ts) VALUES (1, NOW()) ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET ts=EXCLUDED.ts;"
}}
```

Example:

We nedd to add another column from table "customer" and we need to receive all customers registers again for processing.
When we update the connector config, the registers aren't been sent again.

Answer (score 1):

We were able to figure out how to get the setup to work.

We use the ad hoc snapshot feature. We create a signal table in the source database according to the script below (PostgresSql):

```
CREATE TABLE public.debezium_signal (id VARCHAR(42) PRIMARY KEY, type VARCHAR(32) NULL, data VARCHAR(2048) NULL);
```

We adjusted the configuration of our connector to contain the tag "signal.data.collection" pointing to the table of signals we created.

```
"signal.data.collection": "public.debezium_signal"
```

We also added the table name in the tag "table.include.list" and since we used the configuration to tell which columns we want kafka connect to migrate, we had to add the columns of the signal table also in the tag "column.include. list"

```
"column.include.list": "public.customer.id,(other columns...),public.debezium_signal.id,public.debezium_signal.type,public.debezium_signal.data",
"table.include.list": "public.customer,public.debezium_signal",
```

After that, we just added a record to the signals table, pointing to which table we want kafka connect to re-snapshot the records.

```
INSERT INTO debezium_signal (id, type, data) VALUES (gen_random_uuid(), 'execute-snapshot', '{"data-collections": ["public.customer"]}');
```